# How do I create a specified shape using TextView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

[image]

Please I am facing a challenge creating and getting the right angles of a shape in XML using android studio. I want the shape to cut out through the screen, but I am not getting the right angles.
I have already created an oval shape in my drawable folder, and I need the shape to position in the left corner of the screen. Can someone pls help? I have included the code snippet and the picture of the required screen needed. Thanks

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:rotationY="14"
    android:background="@drawable/ellipse_shape"/>
```

Comment: it seems like cardview

Comment: @SaurabhDhage , I think he meant , green oval shape with E-Health text

Comment: try creating design like this in figma or any other tool and then set it background to cardview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-

**custom_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

<!--     Replace with your dimensions-->
    <size
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp" />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

**it output be like this**

[image]

And the textView code:-

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"/>
```

Hope You Helpful!